# How to make laravel routing like in wordpress?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Strandart url - site.com/controller/func/parametr

You can make such constructions urls:

```
site.com/category/category1/post1
site.com/category/category1/post2
site.com/category/category2/post1
```

I would like to:

```
site.com/category1/post1
site.com/category2/post1
```

It is possible if i make controller for each category, but is so messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it just be defining a route like this

```
Route::get('/{cat}/{title}',array('uses' => 'PostsController@showPost'));
```

And then use the parameters in the action

```
public function showPost($cat, $title){
    // you can find category and post by titles and show the post
}
```